# How I fetch allHTTPHeaderFields in AFNetworking 3.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, afnetworking, afhttprequestoperation

I am migrating my code from AFNetworking 2.x to 3.0.

In AFNetworking 2.x

```
AFHTTPRequestOPeration *requestOperation;
self.formHash = requestOperation.request.allHTTPHeaderFields[@"FormHash"];
```

Would anyone help me to implement what is the alternative to fetch `allHTTPHeaderFields` in AFNerworking 3.0

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this : NSDictionary *fields = ((NSHTTPURLResponse*)response).allHeaderFields;